# Как игнорировать верхний перекрывающий объект по hover в SVG?

Tags: css, css3, svg

В SVG есть два объекта один из которых (верхний) частично перекрывает другой объект (нижний). На нижний объект повешен hover.

Как сделать так что бы ховер срабатывал не только на открытый участок нижнего объекта но и на ту часть которая закрывает верхний?

Answer (score 2):

Классический HTML-способ — использование `pointer-events:none;` [актуален](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pointer-events) и для svg:

```css
.red {
  fill: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.blue {
  fill: blue;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.red:hover {
  fill: orange
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 220 220" height="100">
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="150" height="100" class="red"/>
  <rect x="50" y="50" width="150" height="100" class="blue"/>
</svg>
```